# Sending data to php function from ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am using an ajax call which is as follows

```
       var ID=$(this).attr('id');
       var input=$("#input_"+ID).val();
       var dataString = {id: ID, value: input}; 
        $("#span_"+ID).html(input);

        if(input.length>0)
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/apps/worker_app.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#span_"+ID).html(span);
                }
            });
        }
```

How can I get the data in my php function edit_ajax() which is inside worker_app
I use post but the array come to be empty

Thanks

Comment: `array come to be empty` what do you mean? when you access that page with the browser?

Comment: so you don't understand ajax. that data is being sent to php app when you call it in js - why do you think it must be in your php script after you load the page? get youself a book, or read one of all-the-same questions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add dataType: 'json',

```
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
       var input=$("#input_"+ID).val();
       var dataString = {id: ID, value: input}; 
        $("#span_"+ID).html(input);

        if(input.length>0)
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/apps/worker_app.php",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    $("#span_"+ID).html(span);
                }
            });
        }
```

and in worker_app.php get id and value by

```
  $id=$_POST['id'];
  $value=$_POST['value'];
  edit_ajax($id,$value);

function edit_ajax($id,$value){
      $sql="update from ..........";
}
```

Is this what u want?

Comment: and what is that edit_ajax function? do $_print($_POST); to see the posted value in worker_app.php and see what it gives

Comment: span in $("#span_"+ID).html(span); does not sense anything..what is span? it will show undefined as it is not defined anywhere

Comment: my edit_ajax function is out side the class worker_app and i ma calling it with an instance of the class

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `dataType` in your ajax call, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: "/apps/worker_app.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success:function(html) {
  },
  dataType:"json"
});
```

Also, you could use a tool like `firebug` to see so the data is passed correctly in your ajax request.

Here is an example:

`file1.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javscript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // catch submit event for your form
    $('#form1').submit(function() {
       // serialize data from form
       var data = $(this).serialize();
       $.ajax({
         type="POST",
         url:"file2.php",
         data:data,
         success:function(resp) {
            // output response
            $('#output').html(resp);
         }
       });
       return false;
    });
]);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <form method="POST" id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`file2.php`:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
      header('Content-type: text/html');
      echo '<p>Response From Server - Your name is: '.$_POST['name'].'</p>';
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in /apps/worker_app.php get those posted values

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$value=$_POST['value'];
```

and now use the values with your php function

```
function edit_ajax($id,$value)
{
   echo $id;
   echo $value;
}

echo $return=edit_ajax($id,$value);
```

now you can get the values in the current page as

```
success: function(html)
{
     $("#span_"+ID).html(span);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>             $.ajax({
>                 type: "POST",
>                 url: "/apps/worker_app.php",
>                 data: dataString,
>                 cache: false,
>                 success: function(msg)
>                 {
>                     $("#span_"+ID).html(msg);
>                 }
>             });
```

on success, the argument function is receiving should be same used with

```
$("#span_"+ID).html(msg);
```